# How to get the value as per type from one column and display it as multiple column in hive?

Tags: hive

The below query will populate only check no and ac no even if there is data in rest of the column. How to populate all column from the value?

query:

```
select distinct * from(
select
      (CASE WHEN b.dtl_typ = 'CheckNumber' THEN b.col_val END) as `Check Number`,
      a.acc_id as Account_Number,
      (CASE WHEN b.dtl_typ = 'AddressLine1' THEN b.col_val END) as `Address Line 1`,
      (CASE WHEN b.dtl_typ = 'AddressLine2' THEN b.col_val END) as `Address Line 2`,
      (CASE WHEN b.dtl_typ = 'City' THEN b.col_val END) as City,
      (CASE WHEN b.dtl_typ = 'State' THEN b.col_val END) as State,
      (CASE WHEN b.dtl_typ = 'Zipcode' THEN b.col_val END) as ZipCode
  
  from  
  (select *from(select acc_id as acc_id, row_number() over(partition by acc_id order by booking_ts desc) rw_nbr
  from TABLE1 where P_CODE = 'CheckTrnsfr' ) d where rw_nbr = 1) a
  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (select acc_id, dtl_val as col_val, dtl_typ
  from TABLE2 where dtl_typ in('AddressLine1','AddressLine2','City','State','Zipcode','CheckNumber')) b on b.acc_id = a.acc_id)a where
  `Check Number` is not null
```

output:

[image: actual output from above script]

expected output:The above picture only populate check no and a/c no and rest of the column is null even if the data is present which should not be happen. All column should populate with the available data.It is possible if i use more then one left join with where clause one by one like: dtl_typ= 'AddressLine1' left join dtl_typ='AddressLine2 and so on, but that should be a performance issue. It will hit DB multiple times.

```
 select acc_id, dtl_val as col_val, dtl_typ   from TABLE2 where dtl_typ in('AddressLine1','AddressLine2','City','State','Zipcode')
```

output:

[image: click here to see result for the commented query ..asked by @Koushik Roy]

Comment: This means `TABLE2` have matching acc_id but no data for other types. Pls check data in TABLE2 along with where condition on dtl_typ column. Run this sql and is it returns any data `select acc_id, dtl_val as col_val, dtl_typ
  from TABLE2 where dtl_typ in('AddressLine1','AddressLine2','City','State','Zipcode')`

Comment: @Koushik Roy please take a look the result i have pasted above in description area.

Comment: `select distinct * from(select a.acc_id as Account_Number, b.addr_ln_1 as Address_Line_1, c.addr_ln_2 as Address_Line_2 from TABLE1 as a LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from(select acc_id,dtl_val as addr_ln_1, row_number() over(partition by acc_id order by booking_ts desc) rw_nbr from TABLE2 where dtl_typ = 'AddressLine1') d where rw_nbr = 1) b on b.acc_id = a.acc_id LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from(select acc_id,dtl_val as addr_ln_2, row_number() over(partition by acc_id order by booking_ts  desc) rw_nbr from TABLE2 where dtl_typ = 'AddressLine2') d where rw_nbr = 1) c on c.acc_id = a.acc_id)a`

Comment: The above query is giving me the desire output but the problem is TABLE2 is calling again and again which will cause the performance issue, so that i framed the TABLE2 query once...but i am getting null in that case.

Comment: I see your data and not very sure how its possible. Have you checked you have matching data in both tables and if you get dty_type data properly using below SQL `select *from(select acc_id as acc_id, row_number() over(partition by acc_id order by booking_ts desc) rw_nbr
  from TABLE1 where P_CODE = 'CheckTrnsfr' ) d where rw_nbr = 1) a
  
INNER JOIN
  (select acc_id, dtl_val as col_val, dtl_typ
  from TABLE2 where dtl_typ in('AddressLine1','AddressLine2','City','State','Zipcode','CheckNumber')) b on b.acc_id = a.acc_id`